# Saving PDF using DDE Command

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, pdf-generation, dde

i am trying to open an htm file in adobe and save it as pdf file using dde commands
i manged to save a word file but not pdf 
my code is like this

---

```
   filename varchar2(200) := 'c:\temp\text.htm';
   app VARCHAR2(200) := 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 10.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe';
begin
   AppID := DDE.App_Begin(app||' '||filename, DDE.APP_MODE_MINIMIZED);
   DDE.App_Focus(AppID);
   ConvID := DDE.Initiate('acroviewA10', 'Control');
   DDE.Execute(ConvID,'[FileSaveAs"C:\temp\test.pdf"]',10000);
   DDE.App_End(AppID);
   DDE.TERMINATE(Convid);
end;
```

---

does anyone knows how to save pdf?

thanks